# asp db receive "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id =" & Request.QueryString("id")

Tags: sql, database, vbscript, asp-classic, request.querystring

I have code written in an ASP file which is not working

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")         
Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("dbbb.mdb")
Dim strSQL  
Dim strSQL  
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id =" & Request.QueryString("id")
Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
```

The message I receive is:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e14'
>
> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'id ='.
>
> /testAsp/test3/continue/person.asp, line 26

I tried so much and still not getting it where is the problem? (and yes I am noob in this area)

please help

p.s. I can receive a specific id by entering the num instead of `Request.QueryString("id")`

Comment: It would appear that your query is missing an operator. Whatever is supposed to come after "id = " is not there. Check Request.QueryString("id").

Comment: Your `QueryString` doesn't have `id` specified, or it is set to empty string. **Don't** concatenate your query, you are open to SQL Injection.

Comment: Feel like this is `vb.net` not `C#`.

Comment: @SonerGönül: This neither - it's Classic ASP (using VB Script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ID field will generally be looking for an number value. So before executing the database query you should check the QueryString Request does actually contain a number. Here is what I do and it will also prevent sql injections. 
Create Variable ID and Assign the value of the querystring to it.
Check the ID value is not empty and is actually a number "IsNumeric()" Then only if both these are true execute your database lookup. 
nb. don't forget to close your recordset and connection and set them to Nothing.

```
Dim ID
ID = Request.QueryString("id")
If ID <> "" And IsNumeric(ID) Then

    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")         
    Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("dbbb.mdb")
    Dim strSQL 
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id =" & ID
    Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)

    ' DO YOUR BUSINESS '

    rs.Close()
    Set rs = Nothing
    Conn.Close()
    Set Conn = Nothing
Else
    If ID = "" Then
        Response.Write("ID is missing from the URL")
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(ID) Then
        Response.Write("ID is NOT a number")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Also the error you are getting is because the Request.QueryString("id") does not have a value make sure the id is included in the url ie. www.myweb.com/people.asp?id=1

Comment: It help but for some reason the id isn't a numeric?! in my db i created the field as data type autoNumbers....what could gone wrong?

Comment: id firstname lastname phone birthdate
1 donald duck 54 20/01/2014
2 arnold shhhh 545 05/05/2014
3 zan klod van dam 39340 29/01/2014

Comment: This code example should work with that, the only reason it wouldn't run is if the id is not included in the querystring ie. www.myweb.com/people.asp**?id=1** I've updated the code to write back what the problem could be if it can not run.

Comment: in url i do see the id "http://media-top.co.il/testAsp/test3/continue/person.asp?id%20=%203"for example but it still getting to the id is missing(first else if)...i am desperate to understand what is wrong

Comment: remove the spaces before and after the =

Comment: <ul>
    <li><a href='person.asp?id=3'>zan klod van dam</a></li>
    <li><a href='person.asp?id=1'>donald duck</a></li>
    <li><a href='person.asp?id=2'>arnold shhhh</a></li>
</ul>

Comment: thank you i found the problem in asp code :" strLink = "<a href = 'person.asp?id=" & rs("Id") & "'>" & strNavn & "</a>"" the = was written with spaces ....

Comment: i tried to update but id didn't work ...."' Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL
  Dim strSQL  
 
 strSQL = "INSERT INTO people ("

 strSQL = strSQL & "firstName , "
 strSQL = strSQL & "lastName , "

 strSQL = strSQL & "phone , "
 strSQL = strSQL & "birthDate ) "

 strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES("

 strSQL = strSQL & "'Cousin', "

 strSQL = strSQL & "'Gus', "
 strSQL = strSQL & "'99887766', "

 strSQL = strSQL & "'20-04-1964')"

 ' The SQL statement is executed 
Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSQL)"

Comment: it write "Operation must use an updateable query." is the same problem of spaces here or?

Comment: You should probably start a new question so you can post your code formatted so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe QueryString, unless otherwise cast, is going to be a string by default.  based on your query you cannot say where id=string, it needs to be id='string', or cast your querystring param to int.

Additionally, as called out in the comments you should look into parametrizing your query as you are open to SQL injection as is.

Comment: Adding single quotes, is determined on the column type in the DB. If "id" in the DB, is of a string type, the query will need single quotes. If it is a numerical type, then you don;t have to specify single quote sin the query, and just adding a string that can be cast to a numeric, will work... however this offcourse is not recommended, as per all the other comments

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem here is that you are not handling an empty value for your `id` `QueryString` value.  Try checking the `id` field *before* executing the code to read the data from the database.

As pointed out by others, be careful with SQL injection attacks.  Always either use parameters, or if you wish to continue using in-line SQL, consider:

```
id = Replace(Request.QueryString("id"), "'", "''")
```

**-- EDIT --**

Also, as per the post by Barry Dowd, as the example above is more for character based and date (and time) fields.

Comment: that won't help you have to use a parametrized query to be safe with SQL injection

Comment: I know this isn't the safest method.  Do you have an example of how this can be broken at all?  I've been trying to find one but can't...

Comment: Ermm ... that wouldn't work.  You'd have to include `'` in your injection to enable that. if you do that then the single speech marked is escaped by being doubled up.  The `replace()` solution I included above is only part of what needs to be done. Barry, above, included a way of escaping problems with numbers.  Your example won't work.